# Как получить информацию (хотя бы логин) об авторе поста

Tags: php, telegram, madelineproto

Использую библиотеку [MadelineProto](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/) для получения постов из телеграм канала.

Посты приходят таким вот массивом:

```
array (
    '_' => 'message',
    'out' => false,
    'mentioned' => false,
    'media_unread' => false,
    'silent' => false,
    'post' => true,
    'from_scheduled' => false,
    'legacy' => false,
    'edit_hide' => false,
    'id' => 4,
    'to_id' => 
    array (
      '_' => 'peerChannel',
      'channel_id' => 1105854822,
    ),
    'date' => 1598351925,
    'message' => 'Третье сообщение',
    'views' => 1,
)
```

Вопрос. Как получить хотя бы логин автора поста?
Буду очень благодарен за информацию!

**UPD** сообщения из канала получаю методом **getHistory()**

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, из постов канала можно получить автора только если для него(для канала) включена настройка "подписывать сообщения".
В этом случае у каждого массива появляется новое свойство post_author
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для группы можно получить автора каждого поста. Результат будет содержать массивы постов messages и users.
В каждом массиве messages будет свойство from_id - это id пользователя из массива users, надо только связать их.